# Can d'Alembert's Formula for the Wave Equation in one dimension (1+1D) be used in three dimensions (3+1D)?

Tags: waves, mathematical-physics, boundary-conditions, plane-wave

The 3+1D wave equation for spherically symmetric waves is 
 $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}   \right)   $$ 
where $u=u(t,r)$ and the initial conditions are
$$u(0,r)=g(r)$$  $$u_t(0,r)=h(r) . $$
If we let $v=ru$, we get 
$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} = c^2  \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}     $$ 
which is the one spatial dimensional wave equation, where the initial conditions are
$$v(0,r)=rg(r)$$  $$v_t(0,r)=rh(r) . $$
References:
"The Mathematical Theory of Huygens' Principle", B.B. Baker and E. T. Copson, 1987, p9
"The Mathematical Theory of Wave Motion", G. R. Baldock and T.Bridgeman, 1981, p31
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Spherical_waves

PART B)  If $\phi(t,x)$ is a solution to the 1+1D wave equation and if the initial conditions $\phi(0,x)$ and $\phi_t(0,x)$ are given, then D'Alembert's Formula for the 1+1D wave equation gives
 $$\phi(t,x)= \frac 12[ \phi(0,x-ct)+ \phi(0,x+ct) ]+ \frac1{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} \phi_t(0,y)dy . $$ 
Letting $g(x)=\phi(0,x)$ and $h(x)= \phi_t(0,x)$ (with $c=1$, so $ct=t$) this is commonly written
 $$\phi(t,x)= \frac 12[ g(x-t)+ g(x+t) ]+ \frac12 \int_{x-t}^{x+t} h(y)dy . $$ 
References:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula
http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse32.html
http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/dAlembert/dAlembert.htm

***THE QUESTIONS:***

***1) Then can we use D'Alembert's Formula for the 1+1D wave equation with initial conditions to get the solution to the spherically symmetric 3+1D wave equation with initial conditions?***

***2) If so, what is the physical (or intuitive) meaning of the integral term in D'Alemberts solution in the three spatial dimensional case?***

***UPDATE:*** The following references may indicate the answer to question 1) is yes.

[math.ualberta.ca 337week0405.pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi6sO-A6aDOAhUpw4MKHemvDNsQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ualberta.ca%2F~xinweiyu%2F337.2.09w%2F337Week0405.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEXihc51wdTvt9s1Z6rxOcdI2g5Lw&bvm=bv.128617741,d.cGc&cad=rja)
after equation 180: "Thus the equation for $U$ can be solved using the formula we have discussed" {here $U$ is the 3D solution in $rU$ and the formula is D'Alemberts}.

[Stanford Univ waveequation3.pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcscGj9qDOAhVWzmMKHZKKBrcQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.stanford.edu%2Fclass%2Fmath220a%2Fhandouts%2Fwaveequation3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHbKSkJIzeZHaWP_RDW9APIVL1a-Q&bvm=bv.128617741,d.cGc) page 4 Lemma 3 and page 5.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267899/2451

Comment: In order for a d'Alembert-like solution to work, you need (1) an initial delta function in position to propagate outward in a shell proportional to $\delta(r-vt)$ and (2) an initial delta function in velocity to make a 'shockwave' of displcement also propagating outward at $v$, as I wrote in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: I _think_ that means it should also work for the n-dimensional wave equation, up to various powers of $r$ appearing. But there may be a subtlety in even dimensions, following [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129324/why-is-huygens-principle-only-valid-in-an-odd-number-of-spatial-dimensions/). I'm not sure exactly what breaks down.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570407